# Spring Security returning 403 with correct username password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to enable basic http authentication with a single static username password for the whole project. I have tried many things but none have been successful. This is the latest method that I am trying

My security configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.security.user.name=myusername
spring.security.user.password=mypassword
```

When I go to one of my controllers I do get the username/password dialog. However if I enter the correct one I get a a page with the message

My Whitelabel Error Page

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

and in my spring logs I see

```
Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [150,084] milliseconds.
```

When I enter a wrong username password, the auth dialog keeps refreshing, so I am sure I am entering the correct username pass, and Spring is verifying that. But I don't understand why I get a 403 error when the page loads.

Comment: Why did you write `.hasAnyRole()`? That makes no sense, because no role can access any URL.

Comment: I want any role to get the authentication. What do I need to replace it with? I'm not too familiar with roles in Spring

Comment: I changed it to `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();` and it's working as expected

Comment: Before implementing you need some basic knowledge. Read at least [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/). However, to allow every role to access a URL, you could list all roles or use `permitAll` (including anonymous) or `authenticated` (excluding anonymous).